# Python while count < 5 Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

Well i just got back to python(2.7) and i'm practicing my "skills"
I written a basic script here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

var = "Hello Word"
count = 1

While count < 5:
    print var
```

but when executing the file i receive:

```
While count << 5:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone of you guys knows what i've done wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be `while`, not `While`.

Comment: `while`, not `While`, *and* it's just `<`, not `<<`. (Unless you're meaning to do bit shifting?)

Comment: Please always copy and paste transcripts exactly: you say your code has `While count  < 5:`, but your error message has `<<`.  They can't both be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try lowercase while ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

var = "Hello Word"
count = 1

while count < 5:
    print var
    # count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`while` should not be capitalized.